# Copying source code from Google Chrome leaves out '<' and '>'

Tags: html, google-chrome

I was playing around with the HTML of one of my websites and messed it up too much. In order to restore the damage, I went to the site which is currently up online, clicked "View Source Code" and copied all the code. When I paste it into a notepad file or even Dreamweaver, it all pastes nicely EXCEPT for the brackets < and >. To manually go through all the code and replace the brackets would be extremely time consuming. 
Is there a way to copy everything, including the brackets?

Comment: You should use some sort of revision control so that you don't run into this problem in the future.

Comment: Never seen that before with Chrome. What's your URL?

Comment: On a separate note - this question technically belongs on superuser.com, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd second @Impulss suggestion. Most likely it's not Chrome's fault, but the editor you're pasting to. I just tried with Chrome and TextMate, and was able to paste just fine the source code of this particular page, preserving all the angle brackets. So I'd venture to guess your editor is trying to be "smart" about HTML/XML, and intentionally stripping angle brackets.

Another thing to do is to explore what `Paste` options your editor has in the context menu (instead of pasting with Ctrl/Cmd-v).

Answer (score 5):

Try a different browsers 'View Source Code', or try different text editors. Textpad, Notepad++, Vim are all great text editors.

How can I comment on your question like the people above? I can't seem to find the option to. I had to post this answer in response.

Comment: It's a privilege that you will earn after you gain enough reputation. I think you need 50 reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to dealing with the default 'view source' behavior in webkit-based browsers- If you have the development tools turned on: right click> inspect element > right click root node > 'copy as html'.